# How to get all ID's of all Checked data in all pages on Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

Hi i have my datatables with checkbox at the first column
i able to get the checked checkbox id but i cannot get all the data on the other page

i have this to render my datatables

```
 var tableDelcar;
    function LoadTableDelcar() {



        tableDelcar = $('#tblDelcar').DataTable({
            //dom: 'Brtip',

            order: [[1, 'asc']],
            buttons: [
            'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
            ],
            pageLength: 10,
            "ajax": {
                async: false,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                url: 'MaintenancePage.aspx/getCarDelMaintable',
                "dataSrc": "d",
                dataType: 'json',
            },
            "columns": [
          {
              "d": null,
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {

                  return '<input type="checkbox" class="select" id="' + row.CAR_NO + '"></td>';
              }, title: "Action"
          },
        { "data": "CAR_NO", title: "Car No" },
        { "data": "FINDINGS", title: "FINDINGS" },
        { "data": "ActionOwner", title: "Action Owner" },
        { "data": "Auditor", title: "Status" },
        { "data": "COORDINATOR", title: "COORDINATOR" }

   
            ]
        });


    }
```

and this is my function on getting the ID's of the checked checkboxes

```
  function DeleteCar() {
    

       var IDs = $("#tblDelcar input:checkbox:checked").map(function () {
            return $(this).attr("id");
        }).get(); alert(IDs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DOM is loaded when you call your function in the other page.
you have error ?